# WebBrowser component c# waiting time

Tags: c#, time, browser

I have following code

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate(link);
```

Problem is that I need to wait 3 sec before I execute next function (line). I have tried to use `Thread.Sleep(3000)` but obviously it doesn't work .

So I'm looking for a way to **wait 3 sec before executing next line of code and sill letting browser navigate to given link**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep()` doesn't work because it doesn't allow for the `WebBrowser` events to be processed.

I think what you are *really* looking for is an event that fires once the page navigation is completed:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.DocumentCompleted += (object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) =>
{
    //do your processing here or set completed flag
};
browser.Navigate(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where I found it, but this worked for me. I especially don't recall about the Sleep statement.

```
        Browser.Navigate(sLetterFile);
        while (Browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
```